# Existing GIT repo with vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

I just started using Vagrant. Now, One of my clients shared a GIT repo with the following files & directories :

Vagrantfile (file)

Vagrant (directory)

Now, I don't understand what will be my next step ? Every resource in the internet assumes that I am creating a new box from scratch (vagrant init hashicorp/precise64). But, here I need to match the box environment that is shared with me.

Thanks.

Comment: as I understand it, you need to clone the repository locally, cd to the folder where the Vagrantfile resides and run 'vagrant up'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the previous answers - download the repository, and enter (cd via command line) the directory.

Once in there - you should just be able to run `vagrant up` to initiate the download and configuration of the vagrant box. Your client will (in theory) have set up the Vagrantfile to configure the machine appropriately.

**Note:** It might be worth checking to see if they have specified a hostname for the box [i.e mynewproject.dev] (found in Vagrantfile or sometimes, in a .yaml configuration file (i.e site.yaml).

If they have - it would be worth updating your hosts file to make sure you can use the host name locally.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Vagrantfile`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) will described everything about the VM you will build, so it knows about the vagrant box to use, you will have something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do
  ....
  config.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  ...
end
```

If the box is available freely on Atlas (such as hashicorp/precise64) vagrant will download the box and spin a new VM. If the box is not freely available, you will need to install yourself with [vagrant box add](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#add)